# mod_rewrite in multiple htaccess working together

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a local intranet utilizing mod_rewrite, which has a framework for running user apps, that in some cases needs mod_rewrite as well, but I can't get the combination of both to play nice together.

I want the specific app have its own `.htaccess` for rewriting URLs, without worrying about rewrites the framework needs to perform. Therefore the app should rewrite part of the URL and have the framework take over from there.

First, the code:

The app-framework `.htaccess` in `/intranet/apps`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^([^\/]+)\/([^\/.]+)\/\?(.+)$   $1/index.php?screen=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule   ^([^\/]+)\/([^\/.]+)\/?$        $1/index.php?screen=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

The app-specific `.htaccess` in `/intranet/apps/myapp`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteRule   ^export\/([0-9]+)\/?$   export/?pid=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

This app has an export function which accepts a certain ID for processing. So, to break this down:

**URL**: `www.intranet.com/apps/myapp/export/99`

should be rewritten to

**URL**: `www.intranet.com/apps/myapp/export/?pid=99`

by the app-specific `.htaccess`.
Now, the framework should take over:

**URL**: `www.intranet.com/apps/myapp/export/?pid=99`

to

**URL**: `www.intranet.com/apps/myapp/index.php?screen=export&pid=99`

My apps work just fine, so the framework does the rewriting as it should, but once an app-specific rewrite enters the game, that page breaks down and throws back a 404

To my understanding, this scenario handles the app-specific rewrites first, and by `RewriteOptions inherit`, the parent's rewrite are handled next.

The frustrating part is, just having `RewriteEngine on` in the app-specific `.htaccess` is enough to break it down to bits. I am obviously missing something, but I can't seem to work it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably that the inherited rules won't work in the context of `myapp`. You need a `^([^\/.]+)\/?$` regex for inside `myapp` because the URI that gets applied to those rules will be `export/`, and not `myapp/export/` (because the rules are inside `myapp`).

So either add this to the app-framework's htaccess file (at the end of the file) or the one in `myapp`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENANE} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENANE} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\/.]+)\/?$ index.php?screen=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need; I've put this inside the app-framework htaccess, so app-devvers don't have to worry about it, and works like a charm.